# Removing spaces between letters of words

Tags: java, text, filter, processing, profanity

I am putting together a basic profanity filter in java to detect profanity on user input. I am not trying to handle all possible scenarios which I know that is probably impossible to solve using a computer only. However, I do want to handle few basic scenarios which a computer should be suitable to handle. In this particular case I am trying to detect a user trying to break the filter by using spaces between letters. for example: "hello, I am using a s m u r f word here". (smurf being the "bad" word here).

In my current implementation I keep list of words which I check the input text against:

```
public boolean containsBadWords (String text) {

    for (String word : badWords) {
        if (text.matches (".*\\b" + word  +"\\b.*")) {
            return (true);
        }
    }

    return (false);
}
```

But this would not handle the spaced letters issue I described above.

Anybody knows how to collapse these words using Java so I can process them using a basic text matching algorithm?

Comment: So, what's your question?

Comment: Remove all spaces in the sentence & search for evil substrings. Will find some false positives though.

Comment: This doesn't seem like a basic case... But the thing that comes to mind that probably not the best. Compare each character to see if it is whitespace. If it is, save the position of that character and whatever that character is somewhere, remove all whitespace from the string, see if the string contains a bad word, replace all whitespace if not.

Comment: I'd like to avoid false positives (such as scunthorpe problem) if at all possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prepare a list of forbidden words, go over the words, convert words into regex, eg "smurf" -> " s *m *u *r *f * "

```
String regex = " " + word.replaceAll("(.)", "$1 *") + " ";
```

and try to find it in the text

```
boolean found = Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(text).find();
```